# Symbolic array expression

Tags: python, scipy, sympy

I'm wondering if there's a way to treat array variables symbolically (something like sympy but for array instead of numerical variables).  So that I can have array expressions such as

```
f1 = 3*A[i] + 4*B[i][j] - 7 == 0
```

or something even more advanced such as nested array relations

```
f2= 3 * A[C[i][j]] == B[i] + 3
```

By treating A, B symbolically, I can change the contents of A, B by using substitution , e.g.:

```
f1.subs(A=[1,2,3,4],B=[[1,2],[3,4]])
```

I can then add f1 and f2, etc.

Comment: Could you write a function to determine `A[i]`, `B[i][j]` from `i` and `j`?  If so, you might be able to coax [`numpy.fromfunction`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html#numpy.fromfunction) into doing your bidding.

Comment: Maybe Indexed. I don't know if it can be nested, though.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your tags I'll assume that you're interested mainly in Python solutions.

There are a few projects that build up array expressions symbolically.  I recommend that you look at

- [Theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/) - builds array expressions for code generation.  Primarily used for machine learning applications but a fairly general project.
- [SymPy Matrix Expressions](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/matrices/expressions.html) - restricted to matrices but handles some of the special knowledge we have for linear algebra.
- [SymPy Indexed](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/_modules/sympy/tensor/indexed.html)
- [Blaze](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/blaze) - a new project growing out of the folks at Continuum.

If you're willing to go out of Python you could look at the [xAct](http://www.xact.es/)  in Mathematica.

There are many other projects that I haven't listed here that might be relevant depending on your application.  Symbolic linear algebra is a very active field.  Each project tends to be designed with a specific application in mind though.